# Finitely generated words

Tags: python-2.7, python-itertools, sage

I want to do an algorithm that can generate words of lenght less or equal to n, that doesn't contain certain strings, and that takes less than a minute or two to generate all words when I generate words of lenght 15 or more.
My actual code to generate them is this:

```
def inv(mob):
    if 'aA' in mob:
        return False
    elif 'Aa' in mob:
        return False
    elif 'Bb' in mob:
        return False
    elif 'bB' in mob:
        return False
    else: return True

S=itertools.product('AaBb',repeat=n)

SS=map(lambda x: ''.join(x),S)

SSS=filter(inv,SS)
```

(Where n is the lenght)
When I create words of lenght n=10, it takes 3 seconds, but I need to generate at least of lenght n=15 in less than a minute, and when I try with n=15, my computer dies. Someone knows if exists an easy way? Or this problem can't take less time than 2 minutos to generate the words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.imap` and `itertools.ifilter` rather than the `map` and `filter` functions as they produce iterables rather than lists. Which should allow avoid creating the large list that `map` produces which would have to contain 1073741824 (4**15) elements.

```
S = itertools.product('AaBb', repeat=n)
SS = itertools.imap(lambda x: ''.join(x), S)
SSS = itertools.ifilter(inv, SS)
```

Comment: How you use the `itertools.izip` function? I know the command `itertools.ifilter`, but izip not.